# Aplicar estilos .css antes de mostrar página

Tags: css, asp.net, mvc

Não tenho muita experiência em programação web. No site que estou criando estava com um problema de a formatação gráfica do .css não ser logo aplicada e criar efeitos esquisitos ao mostrar a página, e não encontrei solução na web. Não sei se é a melhor maneira de programação, mas a minha solução, em que a página só é mostrada depois de todos os estilos .css aplicados, foi:

Na tag 'body' criar um id e 'hidden' na class, na página _Layout.cshtml (gere todas as restantes páginas), E dentro da tag 'head' e do 'script' a função jquery $(document).ready (...):
E a secção 'body' só é mostrada depois de estilizada. Também não parece afectar os tempos de espera em que a página é mostrada e o meu ficheiro .css nem está ainda 'minified'/optimizado.

```js
<head>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //... outro código 

            // NO FIM DA FUNÇÃO:
            var b = document.getElementById("body_id");
            b.className = "";
        });
</script>
</head>
```

```html
<body id="body_id" class="hidden">
  <!-- design da página -->
</body>
```

Comment: você deveria incluir um exemplo mais completo sobre o problema que está enfrentando.

Comment: Esta foi a solução que encontrei e funciona, só não sei se existem comandos específicos para fazer a página esperar que o ficheiro .css esteja implantado antes de a página mostrar no ecrân. Como tenho aprendido muito com o site resolvi postar algo que não encontro solução na web.

Comment: Esse já é o comportamento esperado, desde que você estruture o seu html da forma correta. Talvez o que possa melhorar é fazer o preload de alguns rescursos visuais mais importantes, mas sem ver o seu html e css não dá para ajudar.

Comment: Em vez de `$(document).ready(function () {` use `$(window).on('load', function () {`

Comment: Existem algumas bibliotecas JS que fazem isso https://www.createjs.com/preloadjs pesquise no Google por "preload css assets"